# Banners for promoting the site once the private beta ends

Tags: discussion

I was reading Robert's blog regarding some [essential topics](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/) that should be discussed on meta during a site's private beta (and beyond). I think we're doing a pretty good job of raising issues that need to be discussed such as tagging, the final domain name, etc.

One thing that I have not seen come up is how we intend to promote the site once its out of private beta. I think we have a really unique opportunity to shine in that regard, since most of us own and operate at least one web site that receives a substantial amount of traffic.

I think its also safe to assume that most of us operate at least one web site that serves advertisements of some kind. That may not be entirely true, but I think the assumption describes the majority.

What we need are banners, [standard size](http://www.simplygraphix.com/banners_sizes.html) that we can use to promote the site. I am graphically challenged, so I'm probably going to end up paying one of my designers to come up with something. The Photoshop / Inkscape talented, however might be interested in posting some concepts here :)

We don't need the final logo or domain to get started on these, so I propose working on them now.

**Edit**

I know the fine folks at Stack Exchange have talented and competent designers on staff, but they may or may not understand the quirks of my users. Hence, a gallery of many concepts would be quite useful :)

Comment: too bad http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1924/graphic-design isn't live yet... its an untapped resource I tell you.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely in the pipeline!

You can see the very basic one we have on [webapps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) right now:

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/help-us-grow-this-site1.png

But we need a lot more options, and some with Area 51 stats for the site as well. This is something I'll be working with Jin on over the next few days..

Comment: With the Area 51 stats, you mean something similar to the existing 'user flair' cards but for the sites? That would be rather cool.

Comment: @tim yes exactly!